# My laptop has been stolen. Is there any way to trace my laptop if I know someone is using the same Wi-Fi I use?

Tags: laptop, ip-address, mac-address

I lost my laptop yesterday. I’m living in hostel in which around 5,000 members are living and we all use the same Wi-Fi provided by the hostel. I don’t know the MAC address of my laptop.

I tried to find the location using my Microsoft Account and Google Account but it didn’t work.I just have the purchase bills of my laptop which contains the serial number and some other basic information and I know the Microsoft account and Google account details of my laptop.

Is there any way to trace my laptop?

Comment: Do you really think he'll connect your laptop to WiFi without reformatting the hard drive?

Comment: I don’t think so. I think she didn’t even turn on my laptop

Comment: Filing an FIR at the nearest police station will be the best option if this is the case. There is literally no way to find it otherwise, except barging into everyone's room and checking manually, which you can't do obviously.

Comment: I search some rooms. And it is impossible to check all the rooms. I will file a complaint. But I don’t know what to do if police ask the MAC addresses. Bcz I don’t know it

Comment: If you've logged in to the Hostel WiFi from your laptop before getting stolen, the mac address of your laptop should be in the database of your College/University. Approach the database administrator of your institute and ask him if he can get the mac address for you to file a police complaint.

Comment: A MAC address cant be of much value to the police if you yave a serial number.  All A MAC is is a unique identifiet. This is not typically broadcast beyond the LAN.  What make laptop is it? ( If, for example, it happens to be a Dell it will have a service tag which is extremely difficult to remove/fake - and which will be on your invoice).

Answer (score 1):

There is no good or easy way to do this - so the general answer is probably not.   There are some edge cases that might conceivably be useful which I list below -

I do comment that if you were logged into a website or similar that regularly updates itself - eg an email client or social media program it is possible that it will be regularly connecting to those servers, and if so you may be able to acquire an IP address from the provider(s) of these services - however this will at best give you an external address (eg "Its in the hostel" or not), or a CGNAT address which will tell you even less, but might give you a hint if its been stolen by an idiot [ who did not turn it off] and taken off campus -   Certainly nothing that can tell you where in the campus it is.

I guess its conceivable that if it is still online and checking email/social media you could write some kind of a script to spam your account and get a string of audio alerts which might or might not be useful if they play at all.